# RXJS: Subscription to share operator causes strange behaviour

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Using these RxJS tools: BehaviorSubject, Subscribe and Next

Please refer to the this codesandbox, and look at the console to see a visual: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-bird-0m81p

You will notice the object "C" value in the subscription is "1 stream behind

Consider the the following code:

```
const initialState = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const Store$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);

const StoreUpdates$ = Store$.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    return Object.assign({}, acc, curr);
  }, initialState),
  share()
);

export const updateStore = update => {
  Store$.next(update);
};

StoreUpdates$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((p, n) => {
    return p.b === n.b;
  })
).subscribe(store => {
  Store$.next({ c: Math.random() });
});

StoreUpdates$.subscribe(store => {
  console.log("Subscription Check:: Notice issue here", store);
});
```

When you call the updateStore function, in the console.log you will notice that the C value, which is updated in a next call within a subscription, appears in the first iteration and the older value appears in the last iteration. So somehow it looks the next.call within the subscription happens "Before"

I believe the codesandox will illustrate and make it more clear.

**How do I maintain the correct order of events so that the latest update appears last in the subscription?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment a non-ideal way of solving this issue is to wrap the next statement within the subscribe in a timeout. If anyone has a better solution please do post.

```
StoreUpdates$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((p, n) => {
    return p.b === n.b;
  })
).subscribe(store => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    Store$.next({ c: Math.random() });
  },0)
});
```